# Javascript Delegate issue

Tags: javascript, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function

So far I haven't been able to grok any Delegate function tutorials out there for Javascript. Even less so the ones with parameters.

Hopefully my current problem will provide a good example. (XXXX() is a function I am passing to Fee())

The way I have it now, my "delegate", (XXXX()) executes as soon as Fee() is called, not when I want it to be called (somewhere inside of Fee())

line of code that calls function:

```
Fee(prod, item, "usage", i, y, XXXX(prod, y));
```

Function:

```
function Fee(prod, item, name, i, y, func) {

    var open = false;
    var prefix = "#" + prod + name;

    $(prefix + y).click(function () {
        var feeBoxName = prefix + "FeeBox" + y;

        if (open == false) {

            FeeOpen(prefix, y);

            func; //delegate is called here

            AddFeeButton(feeBoxName, "addFeeBtn2");
            open = true;
        } else {

            FeeClosed(prefix, y);
            open = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Delegate function:

```
function XXXX(prod, y) {
    var deducedFeeBoxName = "#" + prod + "usageFeeBox" + y;
    alert(deducedFeeBoxName); //at present, this is called immediately when Fee is executed 

    UsageFeeBoxHeader(deducedFeeBoxName);
    UsageFeeBoxData(deducedFeeBoxName, prod, y);
}
```

Comments?

Comment: Use strict comparison (`===` and `!==`) when comparing to Boolean values. Regular comparison may coerce your Booleans to Numbers - you certainly don't want that. (The coercion will occur if the other operand is not a Boolean value.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
Fee(prod, item, "usage", i, y, function() { XXXX(prod, y); });
```

It's usually not called a "delegate" in Javascript. I believe that's a term mostly used in the Microsoft part of the world. We just call it a lambda or anonymous function.

You also have a bug in the main (`Fee`) function. Change this line:

```
func(); //delegate is called here
```

Comment: YES.  That was exactly it!  extra points for indirectly accusing me of being a microsoft developer.

Answer (score 2):

If your function is called `XXX`, then if you use this syntax: `XXX()`, you are invoking your function. To pass it in as a delegate, you simply pass in `XXX`:

```
Fee(prod, item, "usage", i, y, XXX);
```

The Fee method will be responsible for invoking it and determining which parameters are passed into the method.